# Laravel: Call controller with Request::create using POST-method and prevent session from expiring

Tags: laravel

Sorry if it doesn't translate well, I use the google translator, I have the following controller:

```
public function call($ruta,$parametros,$cookies) {

// create(string $uri, string $method = 'GET', array $parameters = [], array $cookies = [], array $files = [], array $server = [], $content = null)

$req = Request::create($ruta,"post",$parametros,$cookies);
$res = app()->handle($req);
$respu = $res->getContent();

return $respu;}
```

I call this controller from my websocket server to call the internal functions that I have in my webapp, and I call the function like this:

```
$respu = $callController->call($datos['ruta'],['XSRF-TOKEN'=>$datos['_token']],['_token'=>$datos['_token'],'XSRF-TOKEN'=>$datos['XSRF-TOKEN'],'suplifalcon_session'=>$datos['suplifalcon_session']]);
```

and I receive as a response a page indicating that it has expired

I have tried to send all the cookies and the csrf to the websocket server and call the method, but nothing works, does anyone know the solution? Example of what I have tried:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<meta name="cooki1" content="{{ $_COOKIE['XSRF-TOKEN'] }}">

<meta name="cooki2" content="{{ $_COOKIE['suplifalcon_session'] }}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in laravel `post` http reqest under `web` middleware needs to verified by a token.
laravel provides two ways to send this token to server:

- a parameter named `_token` that is included in form
- header named `X-CSRF-TOKEN`

the value of both is a token that is generated by `csrf_token()` helper.

are you sure token created properly ?

check token in variable `$datos['_token']`

Comment: hello Zohreh thanks for your help I verified the token and everything was fine, but I already discovered the solution, I hadn't realized that in cookie I had to write the session cookie and in parameters pass the _token as in normal calls, use test and error to see what was necessary in the arguments to pass and I came to this solution I hope someone else finds it useful :D

Comment: $respu = $callController->call($datos['ruta'],['_token'=>$datos['_token'],
[suplifalcon_session'=>$datos['suplifalcon_session']]);

Comment: Obviously your comment helped me realize that.